# Embed messages are not displayed in the chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to create a bot using [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/). Here is my code:

```js
import Discord from 'discord.js'
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!')
})

client.login('my-real-token')

client.on('message', message => {
  console.log(message.content)
  if (message.content === '!embed') {
    message.channel.send({
      embed: {
        color: 0x0099ff,
        description: 'A very simple Embed!',
      },
    })
  }
})
```

But in Discord it appears as an empty message:
[image: empty message]

I tried to use both ways from [the guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html) such as a Discord.MessageEmbed constructor and an embed object like in code above - they both look empty.

Simple messages like `channel.send('hello')` are working as they should.

What am I doing wrong?

---

PS. There are no errors in console, just a "Ready!" and a "!embed".

PS2. I am using typescript, so my build code is different from the source above, but I did not think its a problem, but I can show my dist code of course.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js rarely uses that [embed creator](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview).

Normally, this is what Discord.js uses.

```
  if (msg.content === '!embed'){
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x0099ff)
        .setDescription('A very simple Embed!')
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Comment: Ok, i tried that and got this: `TypeError: discord_js_1.default.RichEmbed is not a constructor` and there is no RichEmbed in [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?q=Rich)